# java.lang.NullPointerException: FloatingActionButton.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, floating-action-button

I have created an Activity which contains four Floating Button and a fragment which calls Activity's Floating button to make them visible/invisible but when I access these Floating Buttons from fragment it throws null pointer exception.

Activity Code:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    getInitialized();

    fabSettings = (FloatingActionButton) this.findViewById(R.id.fabSetting);
    fabStory = (FloatingActionButton) this.findViewById(R.id.fabStory);
    fabImage = (FloatingActionButton) this.findViewById(R.id.fabImage);
    fabVideo = (FloatingActionButton) this.findViewById(R.id.fabVideo);

}
```

Fragment Code:

```
 @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_community, container, false);


    SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
    if(sessionManager.isLoggedIn()){


        ActivityUser.fabSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ActivityUser.laySearchCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ActivityUser.bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        tvCreateCommunity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        MainActivity.fabSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MainActivity.bottomLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MainActivity.laySearchCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        tvCreateCommunity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
 }
```

Please help

Comment: Do not use static view variable in Activity .. Also do not access Activity's view directly from fragment .. Create a method instead ..

Comment: Use interface for this

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

Fragment:

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment {

    public interface onHideEventListener {
        public void hideEvent(boolean isVisible);
    }

    onHideEventListener hideEventListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            hideEventListener = (onHideEventListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onHideEventListener");
        }
    }

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);

        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
        if(sessionManager.isLoggedIn()){
            hideEventListener.hideEvent(false);
        }else{
            hideEventListener.hideEvent(true);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onSomeEventListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void hideEvent(boolean isVisible) {
        fabSettings.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        laySearchCode.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        bottomLayout.setVisibility(isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```